# Alexa, invocation name in the middle of utterance

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want the invocation name in the middle of the text

Ex: Alexa, where is my  order?

I tried, but alexa not recognizing this.

Comment: Off-topic and belongs on IoT https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invocation names for custom skills **have** to come at the beginning of an utterance. If the utterance doesn't begin with "ask {Invocation name}, Alexa will not search your custom skill and will attempt to deal with the request itself.

Here's a diagram for the required custom skill request format.[image: Diagram]

Disappointing, I know. Hope this helped!